# update my imac OS X 10.9.5 to OS sierra

Tags: upgrade

i just installed macOS SIERRA which is 10.12

but nothing has changed it's still OS X 10.9.5

so how to upgrade to sierra

Comment: What did you actually do to install Sierra?

Comment: I have the same issue.  I upgraded Sierra from the App Store and it says "installed" however the System Info still says I'm in 10.9.5.  I'm unsure how to back downgrade or how to get to El Capitan.

Answer (score -1):

You first have to install El captain X
You might not can install the sierra if you ox system was made in the early part of 2009

Comment: OS X 10.9.5 was released on 17th of September 2014!

Answer (score -1):

I have a 2008 iMac. Its running 10.9.5. Because its an intel machine, the later operating systems thats are not intel it wont upgrade. Its as far as you can go. I just had to throw out a Canon MP810 2008, as the latest driver won't run the canon printer utilities. My next computer will be a win10 laptop. I am so over the compatibility issues. Apple was great with backwards compatibility. Not now. Still its served me well for 10 years so I shouldn't complain.